# How to get particular mp3 file path in Box Android API?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, box-api

I am developing an Android Application by using Box.com Android Api , what i need to do is to play mp3 file by audio streaming , I can see that i can download files inside my sd card by using predefined download method , but as there is nothing regarding playing audio file so

How to get particular mp3 file path in Box Android API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really 'stream' these files, but you can progressively download and play them.

To download them, just use the same download API you would use for any other file. For example:

METHOD
GET /files/{file id}/content
EXAMPLE REQUEST
curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID/content \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"

...as seen in the documentation here:
http://developers.box.com/docs/